# Creating solenoidal vector field from another 2D vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-fields

I know that I can create a solenidal vector field by taking the curl of another (lets say KNOWN) "vector field" because the divergence of curl is zero. However 2D vector fields result in a scalar function when taking the curl. So the question is it possible to transform a known 2D vector field to it's "nearest" divergence-free field by any other way?
Thanks in  advance